# Is there an API for getting original Properties.Settings?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, settings

When you access for example:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myColor
```

you will get actually a current setting of the value of `myColor`, not the original one which was set during the development of the program.

And I am looking exactly for it -- the values which were set originally as default. They can be seen again when the current settings are deleted.

Of course, I am looking for an API to get those values without deleting current settings.

Comment: You can just create constants/readonly fields in your code.

Comment: @Sweeper, thank you, I know, but it would mean having two sources of those values. Not clean approach for my taste :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find default value for a setting property by property name this way:

```
var value = (string)Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["propertyName"].DefaultValue;
```

But the returned value is `string` representation of the property value, for example, if you look at `Settings.Designer.cs` you will see the property is decorated with an attribute which stores the default value `[DefaultSettingValueAttribute("128, 128, 255")]`. In this case the return value for above code will be `"128, 128, 225"`.

To be able to get the default value in the original property type, I created the following extension method:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
public static class SettingsExtensions
{
    public static object GetDefaultValue(this ApplicationSettingsBase settings,
        string propertyName)
    {
        var property = settings.Properties[propertyName];
        var type = property.PropertyType;
        var defaultValue = property.DefaultValue;
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFrom(defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Then as usage:

```
var myColor = (Color)Properties.Settings.Default.GetDefaultValue("myColor");
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. I guess `DefaultValue` holds serialized value (so you cannot cast it, only deserialize it first and then cast) but I am not sure why `DefaultValue` is `object` then not a `string`. And I noticed the default value is stored as attribute, thus I wrote my code using it.

Comment: Let me check. I guess it needs tweaking. I tried with string in fact ...

Comment: @astrowalker Yes, it returns string string stored value. I used an extension method to convert it back to the original property type.

Comment: Changed a bit. Make sure use the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any existing API but I needed it so...

1. I made VS to create interface for entire Settings (in user part, not designer):

   ```
   internal sealed partial class Settings : ISettings
   ```

this is only for easier using both settings (current and default)

2. Interface looks like this:

   ```
   internal interface ISettings
   {
     bool AskForNewDescription { get;  }
     ...
   ```
3. I created default settings class:

   ```
   internal sealed class DefaultSettings : ISettings
   {
     public bool AskForNewDescription => GetDefault<bool>();
   ```
4. I didn't tested it for all possible cases, but it works for me:

   ```
   private readonly ISettings source;

   private string GetSerialized(string name)
   {
       var prop = this.source.GetType().GetProperty(name);
       foreach (object attr in prop.GetCustomAttributes(true))
       {
           var val_attr = attr as DefaultSettingValueAttribute;
           if (val_attr != null)
               return val_attr.Value;
       }

       return null;
   }

   private T GetDefault<T>([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
   {
       string s = GetSerialized(name);
       if (s == null)
           return default(T);

       TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
       return (T)tc.ConvertFromString(s);
   }
   ```

Comment: There is a built-in mechanism which allows you to get the property default value shared in the other answer.